# 99c movie rentals

Tags: itunes, ipad

I was looking at the iTunes store on my iPad and I noticed that there is  a 99c rental category.

I was wondering when do these movies get rotated? i.e. when are new movies released as 99c rentals? weekly?

Answer (score 2):

The 99c rental movies get changed **once every week**.